# Ubuntu 14.04 not taking the BIOS time

Tags: 14.04, bios, time

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed and my time zone set is IST, GMT + 5:30.

My BIOS have the correct time but when my machine boots into Ubuntu it shows not the BIOS time.

I tried to manually set the time multiple times but on each reboot the time goes wrong.

How can I make Ubuntu read the BIOS time ?

Comment: Have you tried `system settings -> time and date --> set the time:automatically from internet`?

Comment: are you using systemd or upstart as there is a different command to disable the accessing/storing time in utc and revert back to local time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using systemd the command that will rectify your problem is

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
```

This will set the accessing/storing of time in local time

If you are using upstart, edit /etc/default/rc5 by adding/changing this line:

`UTC=no`

Comment: @ΝΝίκος: How are you running `systemd` under Ubuntu?  (and an upvote!)

Comment: default in vivid :P